# Every function called in `useEffect` stack must be wrapped in `useCallback`?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, usecallback

I am new to React and it seems to me that if you use a function inside of `useEffect`, that entire stack has to be wrapped in `useCallback` in order to comply with the linter.

For example:

```
const Foo = ({} => {
  const someRef = useRef(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    startProcessWithRef();
  }, [startProcessWithRef]);

  const handleProcessWithRef = useCallback((event) => {
    someRef.current = event.clientY;
  }, []);

  const startProcessWithRef = useCallback(() => {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleProcessWithRef);
  }, [handleProcessWithRef]);

  ...
});
```

I'm wondering if there is a different pattern where I don't have to make the entire chain starting in `useEffect` calling `startProcessWithRef` be wrapped in `useCallback` with dependencies. I am not saying it is good or bad, I'm just seeing if there is a preferred alternative because I am new and don't know of one.

Comment: Refs are used for storing a html element in a variable, but you seem to use it for a number. Look at [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) instead.

Comment: @CasperKuethe this is a slightly contrived example; i just wanted to show that i was using a ref and the actual type of the ref doesnt matter in this case.

Comment: If you define your functions inside the body of the `useEffect` function, you shouldn't need to store them in a `useCallback`, otherwise you have the correct implementation pattern

Comment: Either that or use a hook like `const useMount = (fn) => { useEffect(fn, []); };`

Comment: @CasperKuethe while refs are most often used to store references to React component, they can be used for other purposes. For example, here a member of React team uses a ref to store a callback function when writing a custom hook: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/ . In general, refs solve the problem of stale state in callbacks/closures, this problem arises in multiple places when writing cutom hooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic way to write your example would be similar to this:

> Note the importance of removing the event listener in the [effect cleanup function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup).

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwK4GcCmBRAZltBjGAGjlTQCU0sBfOLKCEOAcijQEMCmBuAKB7wgA7FPAwAPNuAA2aOAF44ACgCU8gHyIecOAOHwUDcpXkl0FLIoAMy3ltOYc+GIpXrN27bpFwAFm0EAJjIAshCkoQBusgqKaFGCMABccKGkGPEwqnIaCHAGIEZYAHR4SFCsCSZxaAklUsA1MACaXHBUvB5wAO7AgRBdRWwBAemNADLAIjVoUIpMIGHoC1FMxH6BIYtokWg2dtqsMGWCSlkaPX0DrMuYGRNTgjNzC6Q3q77+QdtbO3vaVMQANr5QoAXT2dkOxzggiQUikvHaQA)

```js
import {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';

const Example = () => {
  const someRef = useRef(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleMouseMove = (event) => { someRef.current = event.clientY; };
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
  }, [someRef]);

  return null;
};
```

---

If you prefer defining the function outside the effect hook, you'll need `useCallback`:

```js
import {useCallback, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';

const Example = () => {
  const someRef = useRef(0);

  const updateRefOnMouseMove = useCallback(() => {
    const handleMouseMove = (event) => { someRef.current = event.clientY; };
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
  }, [someRef]);

  useEffect(updateRefOnMouseMove, [updateRefOnMouseMove]);

  return null;
};
```

Comment: it would be optional to pass in `someRef` as a dependency, right?

Comment: Correct: It won’t have a behavioral effect to exclude it (but that ultimately depends on your specific linter and configuration for diagnostics).